# “La nuit de l'homme”: why is there an article?

Tags: articles

I'm wondering about the expression "La nuit de l'homme".

I'd like to know why it can't be just "La nuit d'homme"? (Indeed, we can say 'Un stylo de Pierre'?)

What is the difference?
Is the second phrase grammatically correct?
What is the difference in meaning between these two expressions?

Comment: Actually, I would say that ”Un stylo de Pierre” is wrong. At least, I can’t think of a context where it would be used. Adding “de Pierre” actually precise which pens we are talking about, hence requires a definite article :I would thus use “Un des stylos de Pierre”.

Answer (score 2):

> La nuit de l'homme, la journée de la femme, ...

C'est la nuit dédiée à l'homme, le jour durant lequel on célèbre la femme (quitte à oublier tout cela le lendemain), ...

> La nuit d'homme (pas usité), une vie d'homme, un comportement d'homme, ...

C'est 'la nuit/la vie/un comportement' typique qu'un homme peut vivre.

Comment: « le jour durant lequel on fait attention à la femme » ?

Comment: @Édouard  "Le jour durant lequel on fait [officiellement] attention à la femme",une sorte fête de qui devrait se renouveler au quotidien, mais qui masque deux à trois mortes hebdomadaires sous les coups de leur conjoint... -- Il est vrai que l'ironie de cette formule n'était pas très visible, j'ai modifié la formulation,

Comment: La « journée de la femme » est consacrée aux *droits des femmes* (j’avoue préférer personnellement l’expression « droits de la femme »), pas *à la femme*.

Comment: [Ceci](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+nuit+des+*&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cla%20nuit%20des%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20temps%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20tems%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20si%C3%A8cles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20%C3%A2ges%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20tombeaux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20sens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20feux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20noces%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20pr%C3%A9jug%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20nuit%20des%20patrouilles%3B%2Cc0) ?

Comment: @Amphiteóth Belle recherche !

Answer (score 0):

"La nuit de l'homme" vs "une nuit d'homme", you could think of this as some sort of definiteness harmony. If nuit is in the definite, it reflects this property on homme. Proper Names are definite by default and don't need a definite article to comply.